# std::ofstream behaves differently in DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm developing a plugin. Take a look at the following code.

```
string request(char post_params[]) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string buffer; //here we'll write response

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_params);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(post_params));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return buffer;
}
....
bool perform(..) {
    std::ofstream file ("d:/t/t.txt");
    file << "opened";
    file.close();       
    string resp = request(....); 
    ...
}
```

If the code is launched inside an app, file `d:/t/t.txt` is created, but if the code is compiled to a DLL, and launched from an app running my plugin, the file is not created. But if I comment out line `string resp = request(....);` and what follows, the file *will* be created. Can somebody explain me what's up here?

Comment: Can you try:: std::ofstream file ; file.open("d:/t/t.txt"); ? Not sure , but just for checking. Need more details.

Comment: How very odd. Could you narrow it down further, by commenting out parts of `perform()` until you establish exactly which code in the rest of the function triggers this behaviour, and post your findings?

Comment: `file.open(...)` does the same

Comment: Can you check if there is a a difference between runtime library settings (C/C++ -> Code generation) for DLL and for stand-alone project?

Comment: @aix, it's written I've done so. the critical point is line `string resp = request(....); `

Comment: @imaximchuk, dll is compiled with `g++ -g -shared main.cpp -I ../common -L ../common -llibcurl -o dll.dll`, and standalone app is compliled with `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -I include -L. -llibcurl`

Comment: @Eugeny89 What's your exact platform/compiler setup? (I see you're using g++, .exe, .dll, so I'm assuming some version of mingw or cygwin)

Comment: I'm using mingw. OS is Windows Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::ofstream file ("d:/t/t.txt");

// Make sure the file is opened before trying to write in it
if (!file.is_open())
{
   // print error message
}
else
{
   file << "opened";
   file.close();
}
```

Comment: but how can I make it inside pludin :)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you just said. What's the problem?

Comment: You say `//print error message`, but how can I print inside a plugin? BTW, I need ofstream right for printing something

Comment: Use [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or something: `MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("text"), TEXT("caption"), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add msvcprtd.lib ( Debug ) and msvcprt.lib ( Release ) to your dependencies if using Visual Studio.